# increasing badge number on server side

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I have a table like this

```
|------------|-----------|
|device_token|badge_count|
|------------|-----------|
|123456789   |3          |
|------------|-----------|
|987654321   |2          |
|------------|-----------|
```

I have the php to create two arrays:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM push");
$deviceToken = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $deviceToken[] = $row['device_token'];
    $badgeCount[] = $row['badge_count'];
}
```

I then insert them like this:

```
foreach($deviceToken as $key=>$value){
        echo $badgeCount[$key];

        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'badge' => $badgeCount[$key],
        );

        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $value) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result){
            die( 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL);
        }
}
```

This returns the echo `3` `2`. But the `$payload` is not successfully giving the correct "badge number"

and in the push notification no badge number is being showed. And if I replace `'badge' => $badgeCount[$key]` with `'badge' => 2` the badge number shows 2 ?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm lost. What is the expected and current outputs that are not correct?

Comment: I don't think the `$payload` is properly encoding `$badgeCount[$key]`

Comment: Do you want to append to `$body['aps']` on each iteration? To do that your assignment should be `$body['aps'][] = array(...`

Comment: I tried `$body['aps'][] = array(
   'alert' => $message,
   'sound' => 'default',
   'badge' => $badgeCount[$key],
  );` Now nothing is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the associative array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT device_token, badge_count FROM push");
$devices = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $devices[] = $row;
}
```

Loop through the devices:

```
foreach($devices as $device){

        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'badge' => (int)$device['badge_count'],//very important cast !!!
        );

        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device['device_token']) 
                      . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result){
            die( 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL);
        }
}
```

Comment: @Maximilian lol im done, I just wanted to include to make sure it is casted to an int

Comment: what do you think of the logos? Also this doesn't seem to be working Not sure why. Not getting any errors